# IllegalStateException with GoogleApiClient on Android in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services, illegalstateexception

I want to create the standard Google Play Game Services Google+ Login, achievements and leaderboard in my game.

I keep getting a crash, and I'm pretty sure is happens on `mGoogleApiClient.connect();`

I'm declaring the correct dependencies in the app folder's `build.gradle`. (No errors on sync)

What am I doing wrong? Here is my code. If this is a duplicate please link!

**app `build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mikemilla.mygame"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 5
        versionName ".13"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
}
```

**`MainActivity.java`**

```
import...    

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.games.Games;
import com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

public Button startGame;
public TextView logo;
public Typeface font;

GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create the Google Api Client with access to Plus and Games
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
            .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
                    // add other APIs and scopes here as needed
            .build();

    startGame = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start_game);
    logo = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "fonts/OldSansBlack.ttf");

    startGame.setTypeface(font, Typeface.NORMAL);
    logo.setTypeface(font, Typeface.NORMAL);

    startGame.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.GAME");
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.no_change, R.anim.slide_up);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
    this.finish();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.finish();
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Suspended", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connection Failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

**logcat**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred. Check the logs for further information.
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$h.b(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$h.g(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$b.gU(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.d$a.handleMessage(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: This error usually occurs because of some incorrect configuration, such as not having the signing certificate correctly associated in the developer console. Check your logcat for full info on the exact problem - you will need to display INFO messages in order to see it (and it won't be associated with your app, so don't filter on app).

Comment: I have had this error before. I had to check to make sure that I declared the app_id correctly in ids.xml. I was trying to work quickly and I had the id hard coded into the manifest as a quoted literal string. It could be for other reasons though. If I knew more I would post something to try to answer.